# vb.net many choices in 1 loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, numbers

I have an array of numbers , i want to get some numbers only in loop.

I want to get from 1 to 20 and from 40 to 50

My Code:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 50

Next
```

But this code gets all the numbers(from 1 to 50).

I wish you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, either do this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 20
Next
For i As Integer = 40 to 50
Next
```

or this

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 20
    If 20 < i OrElse i < 40 Then Continue

Next
```